# Selecting text in absolutely positioned elements

Tags: css, selection, absolute

I have some text that is in elements which are positioned absolutely.

```css
.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
}
.line_1 {
  top: 2em;
}
.line_2 {
  top: 4em;
}
.line_3 {
  top: 6em;
}
.line_4 {
  top: 8em;
}
.line_5 {
  top: 10em;
}
.line_6 {
  top: 12em;
}
.line_7 {
  top: 14em;
}
.line_8 {
  top: 16em;
}
.line_9 {
  top: 18em;
}
```

```html
<div class="line line_1">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_2">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_3">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_4">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_5">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_6">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_7">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_8">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
<div class="line line_9">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog</div>
```

(also available in a larger, easier to read view on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/NWKYPQm))

The text needs to be selectable, and it is so long as the cursor doesn't hover over a non-absolutely positioned element - at that point the selection jumps between the selection start, and the beginning of the first element.

I can see what's happening here, the selection is trying to form between the selection start point and the nearest baseline of whatever element my cursor is over.  **How can I prevent this from happening?**  I've tried setting `user-select: none` on the enclosing element, and setting it back to `text` on the absolutely positioned ones with no effect.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason for each line of text having to individually be absolute positioned? Can you not have a single absolute positioned element and add individual lines as needed?

Comment: @hungerstar Working with an old version of PDF.js - don't have much control over the positioning here, unfortunately